# xPath.evaluate only returns a single node

Tags: java

I have the following XML structure:

```
...
...
  <CON>
    <LANGUAGES>
      <LANGUAGE>Deutsch</LANGUAGE> 
      <LANGUAGE>English</LANGUAGE> 
    </LANGUAGES>
  <CON>
  ...
  ...
```

Using my code below, I'm trying to retrieve the languages but when I try to print the length of the node list, it only returns 1.

```
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NodeList nl = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate("/CU_DATA/CU/CON/LANGUAGES", document, XPathConstants.NODESET);                                  

System.out.println(nl.getLength()); 
// Output: 1
```

How can I get the two languages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I get the two languages?

By asking for the `LANGUAGE` elements instead of `LANGUAGES` - after all, there *is* only one `LANGUAGES` element. So something like this:

```
NodeList nl = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate("/CU_DATA/CU/CON/LANGUAGES/LANGUAGE",
                                       document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

Alternatively, find the `LANGUAGES` element as you're currently doing, and then just fetch all the child nodes.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
NodeList nl = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate("/CU_DATA/CU/CON/LANGUAGES//LANGUAGE", document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

or

```
NodeList nl = (NodeList)xPath.evaluate("/CU_DATA/CU/CON/LANGUAGES//*", document, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

`/` is used to separate the nodes where as `//` returns all the nodes recursively